# Inside a namespace, how to define a function returning an object from an inner class?

Tags: c++, class, namespaces

The answer is probably obvious, but I've spent hours over the issue with no luck.

I've got a namespace named "imaging", in which a class "Image" is defined. The header is compiled fine, but the .cpp encounters problems.

Here's the header:

```
//Image.h

#ifndef _IMAGE
#define _IMAGE

#include "Array.h"
#include "Serializable.h"
#include "Vec3.h"
#include "ppm_format.h"

namespace imaging
{
class Image : math::Array<float>, Serializable
{       
    public:

        math::Vec3<float> * pixels;

        // constructors and destructor
        Image();                                                 // default: zero dimensions, nullptr for the buffer.   
        Image(unsigned int w, unsigned int h);
        Image(unsigned int w, unsigned int h, const math::Vec3<float> * data_ptr);
        Image(const Image &src);
        ~Image();

        Image & operator = (const Image & right);


};

} //namespace imaging

#endif
```

Here's the .cpp. Everything runs fine till the last operator overloading:

```
//Image.cpp

#include "Image.h"

namespace imaging {

Image::Image() : Array(0, 0), pixels(nullptr) {}

Image::Image(unsigned int w, unsigned int h) : Array(w, h) {}

Image::Image(unsigned int w, unsigned int h, const math::Vec3<float> * data_ptr) : Array(w, h)
{
    memcpy(pixels, data_ptr, sizeof(data_ptr));
}

Image::Image(const Image &src) : Array(src.width, src.height), pixels(src.pixels) {}

Image::~Image() {
    if (pixels != nullptr) delete[] pixels;
}

Image& Image::operator=(const Image& right) {
    memcpy(pixels, right.pixels, sizeof(right.pixels));
    return *this;
}
...
}
```

Here are the errors:

```
error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '&'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2086: 'int imaging::Image': redefinition
error C2761: 'imaging::Image &imaging::Image::operator =(const imaging::Image &)': member function redeclaration not allowed
error C2059: syntax error: '{'
error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
error C2509: '<<': member function not declared in 'imaging::Image'
```

It's just like "Image" is a random word.

Any ideas? Thanks a great deal!

EDIT: BTW, transfering the code from the .cpp to the header solves all the problems. But the question remains, what's the fault in this example?

Comment: Is the last function being defined within the `imaging` namespace? If not you must use `imaging::Image`.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Yes, it's being defined within. The code begins just like I posted, with "namespace imaging {" and the bracket closes after the operator overloading.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE], otherwise it's impossible to diagnose your actual problems.

Comment: It's done, I'm sorry but I didn't want to make it too complicated.

Comment: @user2562023 Should post the actual compiler errors as well

Comment: OK, I posted the errors reported at this line. The program is big enough and other errors come up as well, but nothing at the header or at a previous part of this specific .cpp.

Comment: This is not the problem but `if (pixels != nullptr)` is not needed in the destructor.  If `pixels == nullptr` then calling delete on it is a non op so you can just have `delete[] pixels`.

Comment: BTW, transfering the code from the .cpp to the header solves all the problems. But the question remains, what's the fault in this example?

Answer (score 0):

I get no error running your code as you can see here: 
https://ideone.com/NmJOpn

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace imaging
{
  class Image 
  {       
  public:

    int pixels;

    // constructors and destructor
    Image();                                                 // default: zero dimensions, nullptr for the buffer.   
    Image(unsigned int w, unsigned int h);
    Image(unsigned int w, unsigned int h, const int data_ptr);
    Image(const Image &src);
    ~Image();

    Image & operator = (const Image & right);


  };

}

namespace imaging {

  Image::Image(){}

  Image::Image(unsigned int w, unsigned int h) { std::cout << "built Image!" << std::endl; }

  Image::Image(unsigned int w, unsigned int h, const int data_ptr)
  {
    //memcpy(pixels, data_ptr, sizeof(data_ptr));
  }

  Image::Image(const Image &src) {}

  Image::~Image() {
    //if (pixels != nullptr) delete[] pixels;
  }

  Image& Image::operator=(const Image& right) {
    //memcpy(pixels, right.pixels, sizeof(right.pixels));
    return *this;
  }
} 

int main() {
    imaging::Image wImage(1,2);
    return 0;
}
```

Output: 
`built Image!`

I've also tested it in VS2012.

This looks like you have an extra } somewhere. Try stripping down your code and see if you still have the error.

Comment: As I posted on EDIT, this particular problem is getting solved if I move over the header code to the .cpp. But other issues maintain, which I think are the root cause.

Apart from the Image.h, I have ppm_format.h. Both contain pieces of the "imaging" namespace.

Ppm_format.h uses a function from Image.h, which returns an "Image" object.
Image.h uses another function from ppm_format.

So, initially, I included each header in one another, but that doesn't work.

What can I do?

Comment: Strip down your code. Isolate the error. I suspect that something elase is causing the error and you did not provide enough code here.

Comment: There are multiple errors. The first coming up is that ppm_format.h doesn't recognize "Image" objects, even though I include Image.h. Do you have any answer for my comment above?

Comment: So you have Image.h that include ppm_format.h and ppm_format.h that include Image.h? Circular dependency.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I saw. But I solved it including ppm_format.h at .cpp, all's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Nevertheless, I found the solution. I had to include *ppm_format.h* not in the header of *Image*, but in the .cpp file, so as to avoid including two headers with each another.